# php chmod return no such file

Tags: php, chmod

I can't understand why chmod returns an error if it contains a variable like this:

```
echo $backup_location.$filename; // Return /home/xxx/mysql_backup/backup-03_13_2020.tar.gz
chmod($backup_location.$filename, 0777);   // no works
// Return:
// PHP Warning:  chmod(): No such file or directory in xxx.php on line 70
```

If I do this:

```
echo $backup_location.$filename; // Return /home/xxx/mysql_backup/backup-03_13_2020.tar.gz
chmod($backup_location.'backup-03_13_2020.tar.gz', 0777);   // works
```

It works, unfortunately I can't assign a permanent file name ... What is the problem?

Comment: `var_dump($backup_location.$filename)` gives what?

Comment: string(47) "/home/pi/mysql_backup/backup-03_13_2020.tar.gz
" 
it looks like the next line is in the name

Comment: thank you i used rtrim($backup_location.$filename) ;) i and everything works :)

Comment: Great. In the future use `var_dump` because it gives the string length as well. Data can be missed with `echo`.